# How to create a library without headers?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

We have modules in C++20, can we completely remove `#include` in our code?

For example, we can write

```
import boost.asio;
...
```

Instead of

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
...
```

---

In the past we need these steps to install a library:

- Compile all sources (.cpp) into objects (.o).
- Package them into a library (.a or .so).
- Install the headers into `/usr/include`.
- Install the library files into `/usr/lib`.

In C++20, we may:

- Compile all sources, but each source file may produce an object (.o) and a **Compiled Module Interface (CMI)**. For gcc, they have .gcm suffixes.
- Package the objects (.o) into a library (.a or .so).
- Install the library files into `/usr/lib`.
- *Install the CMIs into some path.*

But releasing your library with CMIs cause problems:

- We don't have a special folder to place the CMIs (maybe `/usr/include/c++-modules`, I guess).
- Different compilers produce different CMIs. It's terrible for developers to provide different versions of CMIs for their libraries.
- What if we compile module A depending on module B, but using different compiling flags? A different flag may not catch your attention, but may cause potential bugs.

It's not a good way to replace headers with CMIs. So how can we completely remove headers from C++?

---

I'm not talking about the standard library, as modular c++ standard library is introduced in c++23.

Comment: For the different flags, you already have issues with binary (.a/.so)...

Comment: Given that compiler and tooling support is somewhere between non-existent and in its infancy, this question is about 5 years premature by my reckoning.

Comment: @Jarod42 My interpretation of OPs gripe is that going from single-headers+multiple-binaries to multiple-CMIs+multiple-binaries feels like a step backwards.

Comment: I just can't wait to try coding in c++20 style as soon as gcc11 releases and also I don't know exactly what is "c++20 style". Is it too early to remove headers now?

Comment: It would be very ambitious to do it today.  I recommend waiting until the compiler(s) you use all support the feature, and you've verified that the feature works for your project(s).

Comment: The idea that you'd "install a library" at a system level feels off to me.  Libraries and dependencies should be per-project, not per-system.  If two projects share the exact same library dependency, your library management code can share it.  This applies to `.o` files; two different compilers can compile incompatible `.o` or `.dylib` or whatever files from the same source.  It is only by convention that they agree.

Comment: It would be very nice if for, e.g. GCC we could specify options for the default module-mapper, which currently we can not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules are not meant to be a **binary** distribution mechanism; you should expect to supply module interface files (*i.e.*, the same files compiled to object files in your library,
which are not header files) in a very **header-like** fashion and leave the CMI generation and caching to the client’s compiler and build tree (respectively).  The build speed benefits may thus be realized by each client only after the first translation unit that uses a given module.

Other sharing mechanisms may very well come to appear in practice, but the important part here is that it’s not intrinsically more complicated or less compatible than existing build strategies.

Comment: So when releasing our libraries, we need to scan our project and extract the declarations of all functions, global variables, structs and classes to a single .cxx file, which is called a "module export file" and is installed to the system like headers. When users build something depends on our libraries, they generate CMIs from our "module export file" and compile their sources. There isn't any tool to do that scanning and extracting now, and we need to develop one.

Comment: @aleck099: The module interface is hand-written, not extracted, which is a good thing in that the redundancy is the same or less than that of header files.  What is currently a source file that is not installed becomes a module implementation unit that is also not installed, or may be merged into the installed interface (reducing redundancy) without becoming eligible for inlining in at least some implementations.

Comment: A large project may have plenty of headers, and we usually write few headers which `#include` other related headers, providing users with a brief and easy way to use our library --- they simply `#include` one file. As for modules, there may be also plenty of module interfaces. Do we write few module interfaces to `import` them, or use another feature called "module partition" to integrate them?

Comment: @aleck099: You should generally have fewer modules than you did headers, since the pressure to reduce compile time by segregation is reduced.  For example, it has been seriously suggested that the entire standard library might be one module (but that’s not decided yet).  Large libraries like Boost might on the other hand choose to be one module per component.  Module partitions exist primarily for dependency management, but can also be used practically just to control file size.